# Spring OSGi classpath resource issue

Tags: osgi, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I'm trying to deploy a spring based bundle in osgi (fuse esb).In spring context, I'm referring to a db4o file which is inside resources folder. As per my understanding, a maven project will make sure that any file available under resources folder will be available in project classpath. I've kept the file under resources/META-INF/spring/repo/test.db4o.

Here's the entry in spring context.

```
<bean id="objectContainer" class="org.springmodules.db4o.ObjectContainerFactoryBean">
    <property name="databaseFile" value="classpath:META-INF/spring/repo/test.db4o" />
</bean>
```

Once I install and try to start the application, I'm getting the following exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: OSGi resource[classpath:META-INF/spring/repo/test.db4o|bnd.id=258|bnd.sym=taxonomydaoimplbundle] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: bundle://258.0:1/META-INF/spring/repo/test.db4o
```

I've tried different combinations, but OSGi doesn't seem to recognize this file. Any pointer will be appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: which bundle the `test.db4o` file is in? you have to put them in the same bundle.

Comment: It's in the same bundle.

Comment: Have you tried `classpath:/META-INF/spring/repo/test.db4o` (path starting with a slash)

Comment: @Claszen ... I tried all possible combinations.It doesn't seem to pick up for some reason. I even explicitly mentioned the file under Include-Resource in pom. <Include-Resource>
 {maven-resources}, {maven-dependencies},
 repo/taxonomy.db4o=target/classes/repo/taxonomy.db4o
 </Include-Resource>

Comment: Did you place the file to src/**test**/resources (will not be part of the packaged artifact) or src/**main**/resources (will be part of the packaged artifact)

Comment: @Claszen ... here's the path to my file in the bundle--> src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/repo/test.db4o. My understanding was anything under resources (as per standard maven project) will be available in classpath directly. I can see that in the generated bundle, but for some reason spring is not able to identify it during runtime.After doing some research, I found that there are some classloading issues for spring in OSGI,it fails to set the correct contextloader which makes the resource files unavailable, though spring dm doc says otherwise.

Comment: @Claszen..continuing from my previous comment.I even wrote an Activator to get the bundle classloader context and load the spring application context so that the spring classloader has a visibility to the bundle class loader and hence resources. That didn't work out either. I've also tried classpath*: option as per spring dm doc.Not sure what else I can do at this stage, I'm surprised that an apparently simple thing could create a struggle of this proportion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue finally. ObjectContainerFactoryBean is relying on OSGiResourceBundle to load the resource as a file object. Though OSGiResourceBundle exposes a method called getFile(), it doesn't work as intended in an OSGi environment. It always expects a file protocol whereas the resource returned as an URI has a protocol "bundle".Hence, the exception is being thrown. The workaround is to use a inputstream or getUrl. Since I didn't have the source code of ObjectContainerFactoryBean, I had to extend this class to provide my own implementation which loads the file as an inputstream.